# How to pass parameters to maven?

Tags: java, maven, parameters

I am trying to call a parameter via maven command. 
This is how the definition of it looks like:

```
/**
 *
 * @parameter default-value=false
 */
private boolean myBool;
```

What would be the right way to set it via maven command line?

```
<groupid>:<artifactid>:<version>:<goal> -myBool=true
```

does not work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to set it as a property (see [Maven Command Line Options](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html))

```
mvn -DmyBool=true <groupid>:<artifactid>:<version>:<goal>
```

---

As noted by [Diego Victor De Jesus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5042987/diego-victor-de-jesus) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451678/how-to-pass-parameters-to-maven/44452082?noredirect=1#comment130345513_44452082):

> if it is a boolean parameter that should be set to `true`, you can do:
>
> ```
> mvn -DmyBool <groupid>:<artifactid>:<version>:<goal>
> ```

Comment: hint: if the parameters contains special characters, you can use `-D"parameter_key"="parameter_value"`

Comment: And if it is a boolean parameter that should be set to **true**, you can do:

mvn **-DmyBool** <groupid>:<artifactid>:<version>:<goal>

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus Good point, thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.